# expected number of all the boxes having balls of same color

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose there are $n$ boxes, each containing $n$ balls of $n$ different colors. Each time, I randomly select a box, and randomly select a pair of balls from that box, repaint the first to match the second, and put the pair back into the chosen box. What is the expected number of steps until for all the boxes, the balls in each box are of the same color?  (the color of different boxes need not be the same).

This problem is inspired by the version where there is only one box. And using the Markov chain one can derive that the expected number, in that case, is $(n-1)^2$. The way to do it is to condition on the case of the first color, derive the transition probability for each state (# of first color ball in the box), and work out the recursion to determine the formula. However, when there are multiple boxes, I'm stumped on how to apply Markov chain in this scenario. Simply writing out all the states seem a little bit tedious. Is there any more efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you link to or show a solution of the original version?

Comment: For $n=1$ you get $0$; for $n=2$ you get $3$; for $n=3$ you get $20$.  I was going to guess that for $n=4$ you might get $63$, but simulation suggests this is slightly too low

Comment: The original problem can be found at MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41939/a-balls-and-colours-problem

Comment: Here is a very rough approach that gets you the order of magnitude.  You need to select each bin about $(n-1)^2$ times.  If $n$ is not too small, each bin will be selected about the same number of times within $n-1$ or so from the normal approximation.  To be a little sharper you can compute the number of tries so the $-3\sigma$ bin is still at least $(n-1)^2$.  The other dispersion comes from the number of times a bin must be selected.  I suspect there is a long tail above $(n-1)^2$.  As you have $n$ samples from that distribution, the long one will have a probability of about $\frac 1n$

Comment: Find the number of samples that solves a single bin with probability $\frac {n-1}n$, then multiply by $n$ and that would be my guess.  I think the uncertainty of the number of times to pick a bin will dominate over the uncertainty of picking the bins evenly.